# Out of memory if converting base64 image to hex in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, type-conversion

I try to convert a Picture with 7 MB decoded base64 to hex in javascript with this function

```
   exports.toHex = function(s){
     var str='';
      for (var i = 0, l = s.length; i < l; i ++) {
          var hex = Number(s.charCodeAt(i)).toString(16);
          str+=(hex.length > 1 && hex || "0" + hex);
          }          
     return str;
};
```

with little strings it works, but with an big string it give me this error

> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of
>   memory
>
> <--- Last few GCs --->
>
> 49456 ms: Scavenge 1398.9 (1457.5) -> 1398.9 (1457.5) MB, 7.1 / 0
>   ms (+ 6.4 ms in 1 steps since last GC) [allocation failure]
>   [incremental marking delaying mark-sweep].    51290 ms: Mark-sweep
>   1398.9 (1457.5) -> 1398.9 (1457.5) MB, 1823.1 / 0 ms (+ 8.4 ms in 2 steps since start of marking, biggest step 6.4 ms) [last resort gc].
>   53092 ms: Mark-sweep 1398.9 (1457.5) -> 1398.9 (1457.5) MB, 1801.9 / 0
>   ms [last resort gc].
>
> <--- JS stacktrace --->
>
> ==== JS stack trace =========================================
>
> Security context: 0x3f4a60ab4629 
>       2: toHex [/modules/Strings.js:~2]
>   [pc=0x38e2d4f84159] (this=0x2f2cfdf8d519 ,str=0x15dec5a04101 Very long string[9610800])
>       3: encode [/app.js:18]
>   [pc=0x38e2d4f6e7bc] (this=0x2f2cfdf8d599 ,buffer=0x15dec5a04101 Very lon...
>
> Done.

How can i achieve this with big strings?

Comment: `hex.length > 1 ? hex : "0" + hex` (doesn't necessarily solve the memory issue but at least will produce the chars you're expecting). Why do you need a base-64 string encoded as hex number string?

Comment: I wrote an encryption which used hex chars, but i rewrote the function to use base64 and the problem is solved for me now. But perhaps not for others... What are the 1457.5 MB mean? Its only 7 MB?

Comment: My guess is that since node is single-threaded and the conversion loop probably runs for a long time, it prevents GC to collect *any* data resulting in accumulation to the point the process runs out of memory. What exactly causes it to collect 1.4 GB of data has to be further diagnosed with a profiler. The raw byte-size of the string would be ~37 MB (raw 7 MB bytes -> Base-64 (+33%) -> UTF16 (x2) -> Hex format (x2) + all temporary buffers to obtain the final result, or half without the last hex conversion step).