# How to convert big Image to hex with javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, type-conversion

If I try to convert the image to hex I get this error message no matter which function I use. The image has a size of 7 MB.

> <--- Last few GCs --->
>
> 19812 ms: Scavenge 1401.2 (1455.0) -> 1401.2 (1455.0) MB, 9.9 / 0
>   ms (+ 8.3 ms in 1 steps since last GC) [allocation failure]
>   [incremental marking delaying mark-sweep].    21654 ms: Mark-sweep
>   1401.2 (1455.0) -> 1401.2 (1455.0) MB, 1842.5 / 0 ms (+ 270.0 ms in 920 steps since start of marking, biggest step 10.0 ms) [last resort
>   gc].    23514 ms: Mark-sweep 1401.2 (1455.0) -> 1401.2 (1455.0) MB,
>   1859.4 / 0 ms [last resort gc].
>
> <--- JS stacktrace --->
>
> ==== JS stack trace =========================================
>
> Security context: 0x12f0909b4629 
>       2: log [console.js:~35] [pc=0x19b4a892f0] (this=0x308b40ad9b49 )
>       3: arguments adaptor frame: 1->0
>       7: log [native v8natives.js:1210] [pc=0x19b4a6d2bf] (this=0x308b40ad9b49 )
>       8: arguments adaptor frame: 1->0
>       9: /* anonymous */(aka /* anonymous */) [/app....
>
> Done.

How can I convert big images to Hex?

I used the functions

```
image.toString('hex');
```

and

```
exports.toHex = function(s){
     var str='';
      for (var i = 0, l = s.length; i < l; i ++) {
          var hex = Number(s.charCodeAt(i)).toString(16);
          str+=(hex.length > 1 && hex || "0" + hex);
    }          
      return str;
};
```

Comment: What is the code that you are using to convert the image?

Comment: I think the problem is string concatenation, try techniques from [this article](http://mattsnider.com/use-a-string-buffer-for-better-performance/)

Comment: @user3707125 string concatenation was indeed a problem back at the time the article was written (2008) but has been dealt with by most modern browsers.

Comment: OP: It's better that you update/edit your original question with new information (provided that no answers has been given) than posting a new [almost identical](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47963558/1693593) question.